# ARM Cortex M0, BYTE or WORD access, which one is the best?

Tags: c, arm

What is the real benefit of using byte access (instead of word) on a Cortex M0+.
LPC845 does have for all package pins (GPIO) one "BYTE" register and one "WORD" register.

If I want to set a GPIO using WORD register, I would use something like this

```
*((volatile uint32_t*)0xA0001088) = 1;

0000036e:   movs    r4, #137        ; 0x89
00000370:   ldr     r0, [pc, #80]   ; (0x3c4 <AppInit+144>)
00000372:   str     r4, [r0, #0]
```

In the same time, I could use BYTE register
(using this, GPIO peripheral will automatically ignore everything is over 0xFF, writing 1 to pin)

```
*((volatile uint8_t*)0xA000102C) = 1;

0000039c:   ldr     r3, [pc, #48]   ; (0x3d0 <AppInit+156>)
0000039e:   adds    r1, #56 ; 0x38
000003a0:   strb    r1, [r3, #0]
```

Now both techniques are consuming the same number of instructions.

Which one is the best to use and why?

Comment: ARM Cortex-M0 is 32-bit processor, and 32-bit access is the "natural" one for it (as long as it is aligned). So even though it *looks* like the same number of instructions, under the hood the hardware does more work for non-32-bit aligned accesses.

Comment: This is my understanding too. But just as a curiosity, why NXP did implement BYTE access to do exactly the same thing. Could be possible to have different cycles (due to pipe?)

Comment: your C code and assembly language dont match each other.  please provide enough code to demonstrate your example and code where the assembly matches the C.

Comment: sorry, I was a copy-paste error while getting this from Eclipse (now fixed as uint8_t)

Comment: you are writing a 1 to a register yet the assembly language is writing 0x89 and 0x38 neither of these are equal to 0x01

Comment: and the address used from the pc relative load is not shown.  the assembly/disassembly does not match the C code.

Comment: with respect to this part, I cant see a difference between the word and byte modes without experimenting.  byte access to control registers in general are going to look strange and draw criticism but if they are correct/valid they are correct.  From an arm core perspective there should be no difference, the bus will be different with the byte enables and address but that heads for the peripheral to be handled which is prepared to deal with it, even if it does a read-modify-write it should be invisible